# Typescript + JSDocs

Tags: typescript, jsdoc

I'm trying to use Typescript and JSDocs to do two things:

1. Typesafe JS code on build (note, i'm NOT using typescript as syntax)
2. Generate d.ts file as a library (so the package can be installed by others).

Step 1 works fine.
I'm having problems with step 2, specifically regarding the name of the declared modules.

TS Config:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "es6",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "target": "es6",
    "checkJs": true,
    "allowJs": true,
    "outFile": "types/index.js",
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "declaration": true,
    "emitDeclarationOnly": true
  },
  "include": [
    "./src/index.js"
  ]
}
```

I'm creating a single d.ts file inside /types, the main issue is that inside that file everything is declared in modules that I can't access:
`declare module "index" {...}`

Ideally `index` should be replaced with the package name, so that you could `import foo from 'package-name'`

Here's a full repro to demonstrate the problem:
https://github.com/IamTheHttp/repro-typescript-jsdocs

Comment: To anyone's interested, I never could solve this problem and ended up switching to typescript completely.